# Problems with service manager and backuground music

Tags: android, service, andengine, background-music

I have a class that extends a service manager of playing the background music of my application. When you exit the application completely stops the service successfully but when you exit the application with the Home button background music stops but the latter resumes without going back into the application. What can it be?

Thanks.

My Service:

```
public class MusicManager extends Service  implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener{

private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private int length = 0;

String[] myMusic = {"mfx/Track01.ogg", "mfx/Track02.ogg", "mfx/Track03.ogg"};        
private static int mUltimaPista = -1;

public MusicManager() { }

public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
     public MusicManager getService()
     {
        return MusicManager.this;
     }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){return mBinder;}

@Override
public void onCreate (){
  super.onCreate();

//Musica
  SiguienteCancion();        
  MusicFactory.setAssetBasePath("mfx/");
  AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;       
  try {
    afd = getAssets().openFd(myMusic[mUltimaPista]);
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        afd.close();
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d("Kids",e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) { 
        Log.d("Kids",e.getMessage());           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Kids",e.getMessage());
    }        

  mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {            
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
          mp.reset();
          mp.setVolume(0.25f, 0.25f);
          try {
            SiguienteCancion();
            MusicFactory.setAssetBasePath("mfx/");                   
              AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(myMusic[mUltimaPista]);
              if (afd != null) {
                  mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                  afd.close();
                  mp.prepare();
                  mp.setVolume(0.25f, 0.25f);
                  mp.start();
              }
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              // report a crash
            Log.d("Kids",ex.getMessage());
          }
      }
  });       

    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

  public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int
      extra){

        onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
        return true;
    }
      });
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
     mPlayer.start();
     return START_STICKY;
}

public void pauseMusic()
{
    if(mPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mPlayer.pause();
        length=mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

    }
}

public void resumeMusic()
{
    if(mPlayer.isPlaying()==false)
    {
        mPlayer.seekTo(length);
        mPlayer.start();
    }
}

public void stopMusic()
{
    mPlayer.stop();
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy ()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mPlayer != null)
    {
    try{            
     mPlayer.stop();
     mPlayer.reset();        
     mPlayer.release();
        }finally {
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}

public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(mPlayer != null)
    {
        try{
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
        }finally {
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Obtenemos la siguiente canción a reproducir
public void SiguienteCancion()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int track = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 3);

    while (track == mUltimaPista)
    {
        track = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 3);
    }               

    mUltimaPista = track;
}
```

}

Main Activity:

```
private boolean mIsBound = false;
private MusicManager mServ;
private ServiceConnection Scon =new ServiceConnection()
{
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {                       
        mServ = (MusicManager)((ServiceBinder) service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mServ = null;
    }
};

void doBindService(){
    bindService(new Intent(this,MusicManager.class),Scon,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}

void doUnbindService()
{
    if(mIsBound)
    {
        unbindService(Scon);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}

public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
        throws Exception {                                                            
    Intent music = new Intent();
    music.setClass(this,MusicManager.class);
    startService(music);

    doBindService();

    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
}
@Override
public void onResumeGame() {
    super.onResumeGame();

    if (mServ != null)
    {                   
        mServ.resumeMusic();                        
    }                                         
}
@Override
public void onPauseGame() {
    if (mServ != null)
    {           
        mServ.pauseMusic();
    }

    super.onPauseGame();                                                        
}
```

Other Activity:

```
private boolean mIsBound = false;
private MusicManager mServ;
private ServiceConnection Scon =new ServiceConnection()
{
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {                       
        mServ = (MusicManager)((ServiceBinder) service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mServ = null;
    }
};

void doBindService(){
    bindService(new Intent(this,MusicManager.class),Scon,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}

void doUnbindService()
{
    if(mIsBound)
    {
        unbindService(Scon);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
        throws Exception {

    doBindService();

    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();

}
 @Override
public void onResumeGame() {
    super.onResumeGame();

    if (mServ != null)
    {           
        mServ.resumeMusic();                        
    }
}

@Override
public void onPauseGame() {     
    super.onPauseGame();                

    if (mServ != null)
    {
        mServ.pauseMusic();
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on your main activity put below code .

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (!SoundService.isMediaPlaying()) {
            startService(new Intent(Game.this, SoundService.class));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    stopService(new Intent(this, SoundService.class));
}
```

Also add below function your service.

```
public static boolean isMediaPlaying() {
    if (bgMusic != null) {
        try {
            return bgMusic.isPlaying();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

this all code for one activity if handle all activity your game then set boolean variable on resume and paused method

Comment: Is it only would that be? Should not put the part of ServiceConnection, doBindService void (), etc? And what also removed the doBindService onCreate ()? In other activity in my application also put the same code in onResume and onPause?
Thank you very much.